# invalid initialization of reference of type 'template class' from 'inherit class'

Tags: c++, oop

I am developing the following class, that inherits a template class.

```
template<typename T>
class test : public T
{
 public:
   void init() {
     T::init();
     abc = true; 
   }
 private:
   bool abc;
}
```

On one of my base class I have the following singleton method:

```
class foo : protected bar
{
public:
   static foo &getInstance();
   void init();       

private:
   foo();
   foo(foo const&);
   void operator=(foo const&);
   ~foo() {};
}
```

When I create the following instance:

```
test<foo> &instance = test<foo>::getInstance();
```

I get an error:

```
invalid initialization of reference of type test<foo>& from expression of type foo
```

Do you know what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Nowhere in your code is there a member `getInstance` that returns a `test<foo>` reference. It returns a `foo` reference. They're not synonymous (obviously).

Answer (score 1):

`test<foo>::getInstance()` resolves to `foo::getInstance()`. That function returns a `foo&`, not a `test<foo>&`. A `foo&` cannot be converted to `test<foo>&`. Hence the compiler error.

Use

```
foo& instance = test<foo>::getInstance();
```

If you must have a `test<foo>&`, you need to implement `getInstance()` in `test`.

```
template<typename T>
class test : public T
{
   public:
      void init() {
         T::init();
         abc = true; 
      }
      static test& getInstance()
      {
         static test instance;
         return instance;
      }

   private:
      bool abc;
};
```

But then, you'll have to take care of the cascading effects. You'll have to make sure that the constructors and destructors of `foo` are declared as either `public` or `protected`. They cannot be `private`.